# Combining Kernel density (kde2d) with base map

Tags: r, image, ggmap

I am R newbie and have a question about combining kernel density image plot with a basemap: 
A subset of the example dataset:

```
spe <- read.table(text = 'Lat Long
-16.664969 52.85978
-16.663191 52.94521
-16.664250 52.85902
-16.664250 52.85902
-16.665164 52.87561
-16.664374 52.98654
-16.663627 53.12452
-16.663479 52.85833
-16.663479 52.85833
-16.663032 52.85823
-16.664142 52.85848
-16.663351 52.85834
-16.663196 52.85829
-16.663339 52.85803
-16.665213 52.85939
-16.664166 52.85912
-16.664166 52.85912
-16.663654 52.85868
-16.663660 52.85868
-16.661111 52.86002', sep = " ", header = T)
```

for this I have done a kernel density estimation and image:

```
library(MASS)
    f1 <- kde2d(spe$Lat, spe$Long, n = 500,h=0.0005)
    image(f1,col= colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))(15))
```

now i want to put a google basemap behind the image but do not know how to do that, I tried:

```
require(ggmap)
    mapImageData1 = get_map(location = c(lon = -16.664, lat = 52.859),
                            color = "color",
                            source = "google",
                            maptype = "satellite",
                            zoom = 16)

    ggmap(mapImageData1)
```

But how can I combine now the map with the image with matching coordinates? Or is there another way despite kde2d to do a density estimation with the coords on the basemap?

Many thanks!!! Hope somebody can help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(MASS)
f1 <- kde2d(spe$Lat, spe$Long, n = 500,h=0.0005)
```

You can convert the kernel density into a `RasterLayer` with

```
r1 <- raster(f1)
```

You can remove very low density values with

```
r1[r1 < 0.0001 ] <- NA
```

And then add it to a `ggmap` basemap like [I showed in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34578958/3250126):

```
bm <- ggmap(get_map(location = c(lon = -16.664, lat = 52.859), 
                    maptype = "terrain", zoom = 16))

bm + inset_raster(as.raster(r1), xmin = r1@extent[1], xmax = r1@extent[2],
                  ymin = r1@extent[3], ymax = r1@extent[4])
```

[image]

The stretched result might be caused by the data sample you provided.

Comment: Thanks for that! This is great but I get a white box over my map where there is no density in the kernel calculation. Do you know a way to make this transparent as this is not very pretty? Or might the heatmap idea of @lmo maybe another option? and how could I implement that? Many many thanks

Comment: I edited it so the very low values are `NA`, i.e. transparent

Comment: One last add: Do know a way of changing the colors and by not transforming all into polygons as done in your other question? as this would took days and makes the data to noisy..

Comment: The closest I got was [that](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/nqzBX22MeAQ). Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. Probably, the `gplot()` function from the [rasterVis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rasterVis/rasterVis.pdf) package could help with coloring. However, I did was not able to add a basemap from `ggmap` yet. If you get it running please edit it to this answer. I'd be very interested as well.

Comment: I found this guidance: But was not able to reproduce it usefully with my data, but maybe it helps in your case! http://rpubs.com/alobo/rasterOnGM

Comment: could you provide a data sample that is not as stretched? Unfortunately, this makes it really difficult to reproduce anything.

Comment: unfortunately all my data looks like that (with this stretching), so this is why the guidelink I send you above is not usefull in my case. But maybe with other data it is and might help you for your data. anyhow it would be nice to know If you get it running with your data for future datasets.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an interactive Google Map (as opposed to a static one), you can try the development version of my `googleway` package, and use Google Maps API to plot a [heatlayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap)

To use Google Maps API you need an [api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)

```
## install development version
# devtools::install_github("SymbolixAU/googleway")
library(googleway)
library(magrittr) ## pour les pipes

map_key <- "your_api_key"

google_map(key = map_key, data = spe) %>%
    add_heatmap()
```

Note: I've zoomed out a bit so you can see the land on the left, and the 'heat' points towards the right.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this alternative! although it shows a heatmap instead of the kernel density result. But one question: I can not find the function: google_map in the package googleway or the function add_heatmap. Edit: google_map I found on github but not add_heatmap. Can you help me out here?

Comment: @JmO both functions are in  development version; I've edited my post to include the code to install it.

Comment: @JmO - if you can save your layer as KML then there's also the `add_kml()` function

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try that!

Comment: @JmO - would be interested in how you get on with it; I only added that function a couple of days ago so keen to hear any feedback

Comment: the add_heatmap function works fine! But I have a lower resolution than on my kernel density calculation (also by adjusting option_radius) and I cant change the colours (?),  I tried your add_kml function, too. I transformed the kernel raster using KML{raster} but when I run add_kml I only get a focus on Melbourne. But nevertheless a nice package!!

Comment: @JmO - I've just added the argument `option_gradient` so you can specify the colours you want in the heat layer. Thanks for the feedback, very useful.

Comment: Do you know how the add_heatmap calculation is based on? just by averaging inside a grid or using kernel density estimation etc.? Many thanks!

Comment: @JmO [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer) is a little vague on the calculations it uses