# Split longitude and latitude columns to create grid with equal sized cells

Tags: python, r, cell, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have a dataset with the following coordinates:

```
lat <- c(-5.9, 35.9, 5.13, -3.4)
lon <- c(-19.9, -6, -39.9, 9.38)
```

So the latitude ranges from -5.9 – 35.9 whereas the longitude ranges from -39.9 – 
9.38. The four lat/lot coordinates represent the area's boundaries (four corners).

What I would like to do is create a grid which splits/separates this range into 20 (or so) equal cells. I've tried the following method which splits the instances into equal parts and creates a new column assigning each split a number (1–20).

```
df$LAT_SPLIT <- NA
df$LAT_SPLIT <- as.numeric(cut2(df$LAT, g=20))
```

However, each split does not have the same coordinate range (degrees), which creates grids of different sizes. My question is, how would one separate the above coordinates to create a grid with equal cells, while creating a new column where each cell is assigned a number?

I've read different approaches such that each cell represents 1 degree change in latitude * 30 minutes of longitude but I'm not sure how to do that. I've tried to change the code above so that each degree change in latitude splits the latitude column but I couldn't quite figure out how to that that either, I believe you can use sequence? Even if I could get that to work, the longitude will still have different ranges..

I've tried this in R but any suggestions using Python are appreciated as well
Really looking forward to any possible solutions, thanks!

Reproducible code

```
df <- structure(list(LAT = c(35.61226, 35.34986, 35.17794, 34.60425,34.40356, 33.94433, 33.41834, 16.89566, 16.89561, 16.89561),
                     LON = c(-9.604802, -9.803048, -9.921968, -10.30782, -10.44971,-10.76656, -11.13053, -24.99776, -24.99788, -24.99773)), 
                     .Names = c("LAT","LON"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,6L, 7L, 44161L, 44162L, 44163L))
```

Comment: Are you looking for cut2from the Hmisc package or cut_interval from ggplot2?

Comment: `seq(minvalue, maxvalue, length.out = 21)` will give you 20 equally spaced intervals.  You could then feed this into `cut(values, breaks=seq(...))` to allocate your data into these intervals.

Comment: Do you want _exactly_ 20 cells or do they need to have a specific resolution and/or be square sized?

Comment: @Val Thanks for replying. I don't need 20 cells exactly but I would like them to all be the same size. I just need the range for the above coordinates (grid) to be divided into cells so that i can see how many coordinates (instances of lat/lon) belong to each cell. My df consists of about 45,000 instances with lat/lon coordinates. Some of those coordinates occur more often in certain areas which is why I need the cells so I can assign them to different cells. Just not sure what the best approach would be. If anyone knows how to code that it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @MLEN any approach that works is welcome, I'm not too picky, please see the comment above it may make what I'm trying to do a bit clearer, thanks

Comment: @AndrewGustar could you show me how you would do that for a 1 degree change in latitude so that each change in longitude is split equally as well for all the cells (thus creating equal sized grids)? Would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach to generate a regular polygon grid.

First we start by converting the data.frame into a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`

```
library(sp)
dfSp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(matrix(c(df$LON, df$LAT), nrow = nrow(df)), data = df)
```

Afterwards, we use `makegrid` to create a regular grid of central points and convert this into a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` as well.

```
grid <- makegrid(dfSp, n = 20)
gridSp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(grid, data = data.frame(id = rownames(grid)))
```

In order to generate polygons, we utilize some `raster::` functions. First, we create a `RasterLayer` which is then converted to polygons.

```
library(raster)
gridSpRas <- rasterFromXYZ(gridSp)
gridPoly <- rasterToPolygons(gridSpRas, dissolve = T)
```

This data also has a numeric identifier for each polygon (in this case `gridPoly$layer`):

```
str(gridPoly@data)
# 'data.frame': 30 obs. of  1 variable:
#   $ layer: num  19 20 21 22 24 14 15 16 17 18 ...
```

Let's have a look at the results:

```
plot(gridPoly)
points(dfSp, col = "red", pch = "+")
```

[image]

## Usecase:

As an example, you can count the number of points within each polygon like this:

```
gridPoly$count <- unlist(lapply(1:length(gridPoly), 
                                function (x) {length(dfSp[gridPoly[x, ], ])}))
spplot(gridPoly, zcol = "count")
```

[image]

Comment: @Ioki Thank you, works like a charm. Just have one additional request. How could I add the gridPoly$count column to my original df, so that each instance that belongs to a certain cell would be assigned a number, in this case from 1–30. This way I can group my data by the column "grid" for further analysis.

Comment: you can do this with a spatial join like in the *usecase*: `dfSp$count <- unlist(lapply(1:length(dfSp), function(x) {gridPoly[dfSp[x, ],]$count}))`. Since your question was about generating a grid, you might mark the answer as a solution to your Q to let future users know that this approach is valid.

Comment: @Ioki marked it as answered, thank you! However, the code above to create a new column gave me the following error: replacement has 44157 rows, data has 44155. Any idea why? Ok, I changed the number of cells to 30 and it gave me 42 different cells (gives me 44155 rows), which is fine. But when I try to assign the cell id to each row the coordinates belong to it assigns the number of instances per row instead, which is really strange, and it takes forever, I tried changing $count to $id but that didn't work either..

Comment: "the number of instances per row instead" seems to me as if you have some `length()` function there, as in the example in the answer. For spatial joining purposes you should have a look at other threads like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/137621/26687) or [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/171856/26687).

Comment: Thanks those threads helped me. For those trying to solve a similar problem, I added an id column to the polygons like so: `gridPoly@data$poly.ids <- 1:nrow(gridPoly)`, then combined the two using the following function from the spatialEco package:
`pts.poly <- point.in.poly(dfSp, gridPoly)`. @Ioki do you happen to know how to add the cell id numbers to the grid?

Comment: I would think abut something like `gridPoly$id <- 1:nrow(gridPoly)`...? Imho, I don't really understand the Question.

Comment: When you plot I would like to see the cell's "id" so that each cell has a number in the middle, is that possible? They do it in this thread with over, I've tried `over(gridPoly, gridSp)` which seems to work but I don't know how to use it.. thanks for your time @loki

Comment: For that, no spatial operation is necessary. you can use the centroids of the polygons and then plot the text. A quick google search brought [this](https://chemicalstatistician.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/adding-labels-to-points-in-a-scatter-plot-in-r/) up. Perhaps it helps.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks again @loki. If it doesn't work I might just start a new thread. Have to figure out how to overlay the grid to a map as well but I'm sure I'll manage. Not going to bother you any longer haha

Comment: Got it, you were right, all I had to do was this: `text(gridPoly, labels = "poly.ids")`

Comment: Have to ask one last question.. I can't figure out how to overlay the grid to a map, I've tried it with maptools and RgoogleMaps. I've looked at every thread out there, such as [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88830/overlay-a-spatial-polygon-with-a-grid-and-check-in-which-grid-element-specific-c) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210092/plotting-square-grids-on-a-map-and-extracting-each-grid-information-using-r) one but I can't figure it out. How would I overlay the grid on this map `map(database= "world", ylim=c(-5.9, 35.9), xlim=c(-39.9, 9.38))` ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34578958/3250126). Just ignore the raster part. This is how i plot data on base maps.

Comment: Ok I've tried it and I do get the layers just like you did in your example but what I want are the cells (with id) and the plotted points and behind it a map, can be a very simple map with just the country borders. I'm aware that this may be too much to ask, if you think it's better to just start a new thread let me know, thanks again @loki